# Cannot SELECT table.* because it does not exist, cannot create table because it exists

Tags: mysql, sql, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry pi which has MySQL on it. I´m working on a simple project where I have to only use 1 table. I used `INSERT INTO` to make an entry into the tickets.

Now I'm trying to use `SELECT` to see if the data is in, however, `SELECT` says that the table `tickets` doesn't exist.

```
    mysql> show tables;
    +-------------------+
    | Tables_in_tickets |
    +-------------------+
    | tickets           | <-------
    +-------------------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see, I drew an arrow pointing at the tickets table, which does exist, then when I try to use `SELECT`...

```
    mysql> SELECT tickets.*;
    ERROR 1051 (42S02): Unknown table 'tickets'
```

What's the reasoning behind this? Cheers in advance!

Comment: Try `select * from tickets;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT * FROM tickets
```

**When to use `ticket.*`**

`select ticket.*` is used to see the content of ticket table when you are joining the ticket table with any other table without alias names. Like:

```
SELECT tickets.* 
FROM tickets join
     someOtherTable on tickets.id=someOtherTable.ticketId
```

Comment: @sagi: I know, I was writing the answer to explain when OP should use `ticket.*`

Comment: Actually It is NEVER a good practice to use Select * or select ticket.*. This is a SQL Antipattern.